# How to do you insert array typeof data into apche ignite

Tags: sql, arrays, ignite, sqlline

I am trying to create a table with array data type in apache ignite using following query.

```
create table test(id int,word varchar,vector array,primary key(id));
```

with this above query i am able to create a table test.
0

```
: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> !tables
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+
|           TABLE_CAT            |          TABLE_SCHEM           |           TABLE_NAME           |           TABLE_TYPE           |            REM |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+
|                                | wordVectorCache                | WORDTOVECTORBASICDETAILS       | TABLE                          |                |
|                             | PUBLIC                         | TEST                           | TABLE                          |                |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------+
```

if i tried same with following query

```
create table test1(id int,word varchar,vector char[],primary key(id));
```

i got following error,

```
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> create table test2(id int,word varchar,vector char[],primary key(id));
Error: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TEST2(ID INT,WORD VARCHAR,VECTOR CHAR[[*]],PRIMARY KEY(ID)) "; expected "(, FOR, UNSIGNED, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
create table test2(id int,word varchar,vector char[],primary key(id)) [42001-197] (state=42000,code=1001)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TEST2(ID INT,WORD VARCHAR,VECTOR CHAR[[*]],PRIMARY KEY(ID)) "; expected "(, FOR, UNSIGNED, INVISIBLE, VISIBLE, NOT, NULL, AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, ON, NOT, NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE, SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
create table test2(id int,word varchar,vector char[],primary key(id)) [42001-197]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:750)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:212)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:475)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
```

Now i tried to insert data into test table, using following query

```
insert into test values(1,'ramoji',{'123','234'});
```

this time i faced an issue:

```
0: jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/> insert into test values(1,'ramoji',{'123','234'});
Error: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "insert into test values(1,'ramoji',{'123','234'})[*]" [42000-197] (state=42000,code=1001)
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to parse query. Syntax error in SQL statement "insert into test values(1,'ramoji',{'123','234'})[*]" [42000-197]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:750)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:212)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:475)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
```

Can any one please help me how should i use array data type in apache ignite & how to insert data with proper example.

Thank you very much for your help & Support in advance.
I will be keep looking for your answers, Please help .....

My sample data for one record is:

```
insert into text values( 
1,'in',"['0.070312', '0.086914', '0.087891', '0.062500', '0.069336', '-0.108887', '-0.081543', '-0.154297', '0.020752', '0.131836', '-0.113770', '-0.037354', '0.069336', '0.078125', '-0.103027', '-0.097656', '0.044189', '0.102539', '-0.060791', '-0.036133', '-0.045410', '0.047363', '-0.120605', '-0.063965', '0.002258', '0.037109', '-0.002914', '0.117676', '0.061768', '0.063965', '0.081055', '-0.068848', '-0.021362', '0.055176', '-0.085449', '0.068848', '-0.127930', '-0.033203', '0.098633', '0.175781', '0.110840', '-0.034668', '-0.047119', '-0.008484', '0.035889', '0.103027', '0.026978', '-0.028687', '-0.005127', '0.106445', '0.059814', '0.094238', '0.033691', '-0.027100', '-0.094238', '0.001030', '-0.048340', '0.034424', '0.081055', '-0.113281', '-0.088867', '0.035889', '-0.145508', '-0.244141', '-0.061523', '0.052979', '0.056885', '0.179688', '0.061035', '0.086914', '0.124023', '-0.040283', '0.022583', '0.177734', '-0.029663', '-0.029663', '0.117188', '0.031128', '-0.096191', '0.066406', '0.004700', '-0.080078', '0.062988', '-0.020630', '-0.054688', '-0.135742', '-0.063477', '0.083496', '-0.063965', '0.021484', '0.077148', '-0.037109', '-0.033691', '-0.183594', '-0.072754', '0.015869', '0.093262', '-0.061523', '-0.014221', '-0.003448', '0.011108', '-0.158203', '-0.017090', '0.006195', '-0.008728', '-0.080566', '-0.015259', '-0.087891', '0.003479', '-0.016113', '-0.012329', '0.097656', '-0.139648', '-0.085938', '-0.026855', '0.053955', '0.132812', '0.112793', '0.121094', '0.085449', '-0.007111', '0.044678', '-0.145508', '-0.003204', '-0.117676', '-0.065430', '0.071289', '-0.094238', '-0.030273', '0.120117', '0.080078', '-0.094727', '-0.162109', '-0.077637', '0.021240', '-0.081543', '0.003937', '-0.157227', '-0.098145', '0.039795', '0.039307', '-0.009094', '0.103027', '0.067871', '-0.042725', '0.063477', '-0.049072', '0.020874', '-0.166992', '0.093262', '0.093750', '0.006866', '0.053711', '0.052490', '-0.024414', '-0.032471', '-0.061523', '-0.005554', '0.096191', '0.037842', '0.012207', '-0.043945', '-0.007477', '0.105469', '0.020386', '0.145508', '0.082031', '0.005768', '0.004578', '-0.092773', '-0.138672', '-0.057373', '-0.051514', '-0.130859', '-0.139648', '-0.020508', '-0.027100', '0.032715', '0.104980', '-0.002335', '-0.022583', '0.000504', '-0.110840', '0.084961', '-0.129883', '-0.017456', '-0.000359', '0.107910', '0.088867', '0.044678', '0.025146', '0.023804', '0.081055', '0.023682', '-0.109863', '0.005371', '-0.017700', '-0.033936', '-0.032959', '-0.164062', '0.095703', '-0.018311', '0.005310', '-0.034424', '-0.044189', '-0.066406', '-0.017944', '-0.029663', '-0.007599', '-0.051270', '-0.054199', '0.089355', '-0.071777', '0.015259', '-0.082520', '-0.031738', '0.035645', '-0.021240', '-0.059326', '-0.013062', '0.046875', '0.023071', '0.020996', '-0.078613', '-0.008057', '0.019531', '-0.005554', '0.041504', '0.027832', '0.013611', '0.034668', '-0.182617', '0.120117', '0.074219', '-0.041016', '-0.009949', '0.042969', '-0.007294', '0.123047', '0.057617', '-0.053467', '-0.032227', '-0.009094', '-0.046631', '0.043945', '-0.050781', '0.068848', '0.002991', '-0.004181', '-0.044189', '0.073730', '-0.012756', '0.067383', '0.006287', '0.075195', '-0.037842', '0.004883', '0.044678', '-0.067383', '0.009705', '0.004730', '0.020508', '0.071289', '0.170898', '0.173828', '0.055664', '0.091309', '-0.037354', '0.049805', '-0.039307', '0.044189', '0.062500', '0.048584', '-0.053223', '0.048828', '-0.130859', '-0.028931', '-0.036133', '-0.060791', '-0.057373', '0.123047', '-0.082520', '-0.011902', '0.125000', '0.001358', '0.063965', '-0.106445', '-0.143555', '-0.042236', '0.024048', '-0.168945', '-0.088867', '-0.080566', '0.064941', '0.061279', '-0.047363', '-0.058838', '-0.047607', '0.014465', '-0.062500']");
```

How do i insert this much big data for my third column which should be of type Array.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite's SQL does not have syntax for reading or writing arrays. You can store arrays in text form if you like (for example, you can store JSON snippets in `VARCHAR` columns), or you can store arrays as fields in POJO objects using Ignite's Java APIs (they will not be accessible as SQL table columns in this case).

You can create an `ARRAY` column, but there is no way to populate it with array literal currently.